# RADami Package: creating object class 'phylog'

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I have a phylogenetic tree "m20.mlbtbs" with class 'phylo' that  I have to convert it to class 'phylog' to be able to plot.
I have tried using `as.phylo` function, however I receive the 'length' argument error

```
# read tree
 treedata <- read.tree("m20.mlbtbs")

 class(treedata)

 [1] "phylo"

 # creating phylog file
 (treephylog  <-  as.phylo(treedata, 'phylog'))
```

when executing, the function asks me for some integer that I don't know!

1:

2:

then when I skip this by pressing enter, I receive this error `Error in numeric(dim(tr$edge)[1]) : invalid 'length' argument`

I don't know what to put as length argument, there is no explanation in the documentation, not to my understanding at least! any ideas pleas?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! I think you may be using the wrong function for your purpose. If you want to create an object of class 'phylog' , maybe you need to use the ```phylog``` function the ```ade4``` package?  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ade4/versions/1.7-13/topics/phylog

Comment: Hi, I have used that function, it didn't work either